# Not retrieving the correct value from a form

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, web

So this is weird because it was working earlier but now its not.
I have an html page form:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div class="form-line">
            <input type="email" id="email" runat="server" 
                class="form-control" name="Email" placeholder="Email" required>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the code in the back for the button click to edit the person's email:

```
userid = Convert.ToInt32(Session["ID"]);
UserClass user = sc.GetUser(userid);

Debug.Print("newemail from form " + " " + email.Value);

user.Email = email.Value;

if(sc.EditUser(userid, user))
{
    messageDiv.Visible = true;
    message.Value = "Successfully updated your email ";          
}
```

But the email.value is not correct.
In page load I have email.value equal to the original email of the user, once the user changes it and clicks edit, I retrieve the changed email.value. But apparently it gives the original email.value and not what the user typed. It was working fine before, but now I don't know why it does this. Please help.
Thanks

Edit: I just tested now by leaving the email.value blank when the page loads. It works fine then. But why won't it work when I have email.value equal to the user's original email.

Comment: This is always worth a try if you've been moving things around (I just had to do it). Comment-out the button's code, then go back to the form and double-click the button to create a new event handler. Then copy your saved (commented) code into the new handler.

Comment: @wazz I will try that, I have the same problem in another page too.

Comment: SMTP you can send on one email with an instance of the class.  You have to create a new instance for each email using "new SMTP().

Comment: I am not sending emails, just allowing a user to change their email. @jdweng

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was being dumb.
I just needed:

```
if(!IsPostBack){
 \\then set all to original values like 
 email.value=user.email;
}
```